# .Net catch alert events

Tags: .net, windows, events, alert

How does one catch alerts in Windows?  For example if Outlook has a calendar event such as "You have a meeting in 5 minutes" that is triggered and pops an alert, I want my program to also get the event so I can do something else, such as make a robot arm wave a flag so someone not at the keyboard can know there is an alert.

Is it a regular event catch?  Where is a list of events one can catch?

Comment: You'll need to use the Outlook Interop and tie into something like BeforeReminderShow event.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook?view=outlook-pia

Comment: I need to do this from WUP which is .NetCore but the BeforeReminderSHow is in .NetFramework whic is incompatible.  Any ides how to do this in UWP?